# How do I design this rails database relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, many-to-many

Ok so I have users and companies. I have 95% of the users will have one and only one company so I wanted to do a one to many.

#### Users Table

```
create_table "users"
  string   "email",
  string   "first_name"
  string   "last_name"
  string   "phone_number"
  integer  "company_id"
```

But the problem is there are admins that need to be associated to more then one company and a few users in the system that have 2 companies.

So then I assumed a join table because of the many to many relationship

#### Join Table

```
"company_users"
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
```

But I have to assess the users company so frequently that I want to be able to access the company easily and hate to have a join table for 5% of the users. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way out of using the linking table, unless you leave out the data about the admins with multiple companies.  I suggest you track both the many-to-many and track a primary company.

```
 class User
   belongs_to :primary_company, :class_name => Company
   has_many :company_users
   has_many :companies, :through => :company_users
 end
```

Comment: so with this approach do i need a company_id in the users table and do i need a companies table and a company_users user table as well....can you clarify

Comment: This is a good option also. You'll have to find an optimized way to check whether the user has just one or multiple companies.

Comment: yes but what about your approach `  belongs_to :primary_company, :class_name => Company` how does this work

Comment: You need a primary_company_id field in the users table.  Make sure you save one of the company ids in this field.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even if there were only one single user in the system that had more than one company, it then becomes many-to-many.

1. You could require that the user have two records, one for each company, but that seems not ideal.
2. You could put 2 foreign keys to Company on User and declare `belongs_to :company, foreign_key: 'company1_id'` twice using different foreign keys. **Not ideal** at all, but it *could* work.
3. You could use a database that supports arrays and have an array of company_ids. This won't easily work with ActiveRecord though. However, if using MongoDB is an option, Mongoid has good support for this.
4. Most likely, you're just going to have to have a joins table. I'd consider putting another field on there for the role (admin, employee, etc) and call the model Position. Then a user `has_many :positions` and `has_many :companies, through: :positions`. If this is going to cause an awful lot of joins, you'll want to find a way to cache it. Caching is actually really easy in Rails.

[Rails Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)
[Low-level caching in Rails](http://www.tmatthew.net/blog/rails-caching-example)

Comment: Do you mean have the role in the positions join table

Comment: Yeah... I'd make a Position model with fields user_id, company_id, and role.

Comment: and then as a user how do i access the first company User.first.positions or is that not correct

Comment: Well, on the User declare: `has_many :positions` and `has_many :companies, through: :positions`. To get a user's first company: `user.companies.first`

Comment: @tybo0103 - how does the other end of this relation look like in the position model

Comment: Position model is simply: `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :company`

Answer (score 0):

You can denormalize.

Add a boolean flag '`only_1_company`'.

Maintain it with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read the answer and now feel that your problem is in

"I want to be able to access the company easily and hate to have a join table for 5% of the users."

What do you 'hate' this fact?  How is the 'only 5%' actually affecting either the application architecture or performance or usability?

Focus on the issue that is showing up for your users.  If they find the ui confusing or too slow, then work on the basis of that issue.

Trying to eliminate 'possible' future performance problems is generally considered to be a poor use of time.  The application may well change considerably by that time.  Also, addressing performance may mean approaches like denormalization and you definitely don't want to use such approaches until the exact problem is identified.

Also databases are made to be very efficient in looking up records through join tables so again I would not worry about inefficiencies unless they are causing actual problems right now.